# ProGuard Android obfuscate only one of several library modules (with the same build.gradle)

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, minify

I have develope some library modules for an ocr solution and I want to obfuscate them. I tried with minifyEnabled true and I got some issues. One of these modules is well obfuscated according to the proguard file but the others still aren't obfuscated with the same configuration.

This is the module that is well obfuscated:

The `build.gradle` of this module:

[image: build.gradle of module 1]

And the proguard file:

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keep public class com.tm.baseocr.fragments.* {
 public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.tm.baseocr.processors.* {
public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.tm.baseocr.camera.* {
 public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.tm.baseocr.OcrPermissionManager {
 public static *;
}
```

On the other hand I have this module:

[image: files tree of module 2]

as you can see the mapping file is not generated

and here is the build.gradle code of this module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
    compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.+'
    compile project(':dlib')
    compile project(':baseocr')
}
```

and the proguar file for this second module:

```
-keep public class com.tm.dniocr.model.* {
    public *;
}
```

For this second module I get an aar with no ofuscated code, not even a var or method, just nothing...

I don't understand what's wrong with my config files, if anyone has an idea, I would appreciate the help :)